# Use node-wkhtmltopdf with HTML in memory

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to convert HTML into a PDF, but the HTML is generated dynamically and never actually served up.  I've been using node-html-pdf but it has some issues I've found difficult to overcome (known, long-standing bugs).

I thought I'd give wkhtmltopdf (via node-wkhtmltopdf) a try, but it expects a URL.

My current thought (which isn't great) is to expose the HTML via express since I'm already exposing a REST API with this server.  While doing this isn't rocket science, it seems pretty complicated to just hand something content from memory.

Does anyone have a good pattern for using wkhtmltopdf from node with HTML held in memory?

Comment: Did you read the docs? You can pass a HTML string and it returns a stream, `wkhtmltopdf('<h1>Test</h1><p>Hello world</p>')`

Comment: I honestly tried - I looked [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wkhtmltopdf) and [here](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).  Even after you having said this I can find no reference to that information - what documentation are you looking at?  That is an honest question - clearly I'm not looking in the right place.

Comment: apologies, I was referring to another package with the same name: https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf

Comment: That seems to be a better package to use anyway - thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently there are two npm packages for this.  If you google 'node wkhtmltopdf' you are likely to run into this one first: [node-wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-wkhtmltopdf)

...but if you look further you'll find: [wkhtmltopdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wkhtmltopdf) which is seems more actively maintained and has documentation explaining how to use it directly, as mentioned by @Ben Fortune in the comments above.

Using the correct package, it seems well explained how to use HTML directly.